# didUpdateLocations not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cllocationmanager

I have my object set as the locationManager's delegate, and the didChangeAuthorizationStatus method is called, which does this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

I also have this method, which never gets called following this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    if locations.count == 0 {
        return
    }

    //Do stuff
}
```

Any thoughts as to why this might not be being called? I suppose the object being deallocated is an option, but then it'd also be deallocated by the time it hit the authorizationStatus method.

Comment: That's done elsewhere, and results in that first delegate method being called.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is way late for an answer, but I stumbled across this when I was having the same issue (`didChangeAuthorizationStatus` was being called but not `didUpdateLocations`). Well of course it's something not code related, but rather I was testing in the simulator which did not have a location set. Thus the location was never found, resulting in `didUpdateLocations` never being called.

To fix this... in the simulator go to `Debug -> Location-> <choose location>`.

**EDIT** It should also be noted that `locationManager:didFailWithError:` will run if the location is not set in the simulator, as you'd expect.

Comment: Another thing is that you shouldn't have both NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysInUsageDescription at the same time. I'm not actually sure if that makes a difference but deleting NSLocationAlwaysInUsageDescription seemed to help for me.

Answer (score 6):

It's working in **iOS 10** and **iOS 11** as well,

Create **property** of **CLLocationManager** using **strong** and add **CLLocationManagerDelegate**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

Add below properties into your **info.plist** file

```
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
Privacy - Location Usage Description
```

Add below method in to your **.m file**

```
-(void)getCurrentLocation
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate=self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and just **call** `[self getCurrentLocation]` **method**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from my app:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    ...
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.Fitness
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10   // 10m
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // get current location
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .Authorized {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

You have to put the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in your `Info.plist` and set the value to the authorization question. This is a requirement as of iOS 8.

Comment: I already did that, resulting in the first method being called.

Comment: Are you sure you gave permission to use location services? Check the privacy settings in the settings app for that. Or try to completely uninstall and reinstall the app so you will get asked for permission again.